# Single Sign On IIS 7 migration

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, single-sign-on

I have two web applications on old server with IIS 6 with SSO and it works perfect. Now I have new server with IIS 7 and after migration web applications SSO stopped working - when I try go to second application Login page is shown again...

Can somebody tell me what i doing wrong or what I don't know?

here is first web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="LoginR.aspx" timeout="20" />
</authentication>
<machineKey decryption="AES" decryptionKey="6A6F8E0BCFF28507DDF6316D4BE0CB2AEA85501D0BED1282" validation="SHA1" validationKey="01D0AECBA272DA4662076316AF00F9F2C8F07E12349D1725587612769C9A7B8048AD26BC2298AB2A0D18D2CAF2FC22762E1A3737CFA7EE0E46771DDAAE5B6E1C" />
```

and second web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Http://NEWServerName/FirstAppName/LoginR.aspx" timeout="20" protection="All" path="/" domain="XXX" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
    <machineKey decryption="AES" decryptionKey="6A6F8E0BCFF28507DDF6316D4BE0CB2AEA85501D0BED1282" validationKey="01D0AECBA272DA4662076316AF00F9F2C8F07E12349D1725587612769C9A7B8048AD26BC2298AB2A0D18D2CAF2FC22762E1A3737CFA7EE0E46771DDAAE5B6E1C" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set application pools to integrated mode.